# Trying to do a JTable which adds data from a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to do code that adds a row to a `JTable`. I type but nothing shows up. My `showMessageDialog` also has an error.

Does anyone know how I can rewrite the code?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;

public class JTABEL extends Component {
private JPanel panel1;
private JLabel Name;
private JLabel Age;
private JLabel Class;
private JTextField enterNameTextField;
private JTextField Agefield;
private JTextField EnterClassField;
private JTable Table;
private JButton saveButton;

public JTABEL() {
    saveButton.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jtable");
        frame.setContentPane(new JTABEL().panel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (enterNameTextField.getText().equals("") || Agefield.getText().equals("") || 
EnterClassField.getText().equals("")) {
        showMessageDialog(this, "please Enter all Data");
    } else {
        String data[] = {enterNameTextField.getText(), Agefield.getText(), 
EnterClassField.getText()};

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getModel();
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{enterNameTextField.getText(), Agefield.getText(), 
EnterClassField.getText()});
        showMessageDialog(this, "Add Data Successfully");
        enterNameTextField.setText("");
        Agefield.setText("");
        EnterClassField.setText("");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't use that form of a lambda for your ActionListener since you can't pass an ActionEvent to the method. See: https://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/java-8-lambda-listener-example for an example. Also, 1) variable names should NOT start with an upper case character 2) class names should NOT be fully capitalized. Learn of follow Java conventions. Any text book will follow the standards.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I created the following GUI.

[image: JTable Example 1]

Here's the same GUI after adding a couple of students.

[image: JTable Example 2]

## Explanation

The [model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern is useful when creating a Swing application.  The name implies that you create the model first, then the view, then the controller.

An application model is made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.

A Swing view is one `JFrame` with one or more `JPanels`.  The view displays the contents of the model.  The view does not modify the model.

Each Swing `ActionListener` is a controller.  The controllers update the model.

### Model

I created two model classes.  The `Student` class holds a name, age, and class.

The `JTableModel` class holds the `DefaultTableModel` for the `JTable`.

### View

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that all Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a `JFrame` and two `JPanels`.  One `JPanel` holds the `JTable` and the other `JPanel` holds the add student form.  The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  I placed the table `JPanel` in the center and the form `JPanel` on the east side.

The table `JPanel` uses a `BorderLayout`.  The `JTable` is placed inside of a `JScrollPane`.  The `JScrollPane` is placed inside of the table `JPanel` in the center.

The form `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout` to create a form structure `JPanel`.

Complete explanations of all the [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) can be found in the Oracle tutorial.

### Controller

The anonymous `JButton` `ActionListener` checks to see if the fields have been typed.  If so, a `Student` instance is created and passed to the application model.  If not, an error display pops up.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JTableExample());
    }
    
    private final JTableModel model;
    
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private JTextField nameField, ageField, classField;
    
    public JTableExample() {
        this.model = new JTableModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("JTable Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createAddPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JTable table = new JTable(model.getTableModel());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createAddPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Name:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        nameField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(nameField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Age:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        ageField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(ageField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Class:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        classField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(classField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Add Student");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String name = nameField.getText().trim();
                String ageString = ageField.getText().trim();
                String level = classField.getText().trim();
                
                if (name.isEmpty() || ageString.isEmpty() || level.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            frame, "Please enter all information");
                    return;
                }
                
                int age = getAge(ageString);
                if (age > 0) {
                    model.addStudent(new Student(name, age, level));
                    clearInputFields();
                }
            }

            private int getAge(String ageString) {
                int age = -1;
                try {
                    age = Integer.valueOf(ageString);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            frame, "Please enter a numeric age");
                }
                return age;
            }

            private void clearInputFields() {
                nameField.setText("");
                ageField.setText("");
                classField.setText("");
                
                nameField.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class JTableModel {
        
        private final DefaultTableModel tableModel;
        
        public JTableModel() {
            this.tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
            tableModel.addColumn("Name");
            tableModel.addColumn("Age");
            tableModel.addColumn("Class");
        }
        
        public void addStudent(Student student) {
            Object[] rowData = new Object[3];
            rowData[0] = student.getName();
            rowData[1] = student.getAge();
            rowData[2] = student.getLevel();
            tableModel.addRow(rowData);
        }

        public DefaultTableModel getTableModel() {
            return tableModel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Student {
        
        private final int age;
        
        private final String level, name;

        public Student(String name, int age, String level) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.level = level;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public String getLevel() {
            return level;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i've learned a lot from this code. I'm trying to improve my skills as much as possible.